# Passing data from one VM to another VM, using Unity and prism EventAggregator

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dependency-injection, prism

Trying to pass data from one ViewModel to another using prism EventAggregator, but when I debug on the subscriber, the data is null.

Using version 5.0 of prism.

**Update**

Okay, I have tried implement the EventAggregator using prism 5.0 version. It still dosen't work, but here is what I have done.

**1: Create event class**

```
public class RoomsSelectedEvent : PubSubEvent<ObservableCollection<Room>>
{

}
```

**2: Inject IEventAggregator on publisher ViewModel (BookingViewModel)**

```
public class BookingViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, IViewBookingViewModel
{
    //aggregator 
    protected readonly IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;

    //commands
    public ICommand ContinueCommand { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<Room> RoomsList { get; private set; }        
    public ObservableCollection<RoomList> DropDownRooms { get; private set; }
    public ObservableCollection<CustomerList> DropDownCustomers { get; private set; }

    //enities
    private readonly IDialogService<ContactDetailsView> _dialogServiceContactView;
    private readonly IGetRoomsService _getRoomsService;

    public BookingViewModel(IDialogService<ContactDetailsView> dialogServiceContactview, IGetRoomsService GetRoomsService, IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        // Injection
        _dialogServiceContactView = dialogServiceContactview;
        _getRoomsService = GetRoomsService;
        _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;

        //commands
        ContinueCommand = new RelayCommand(ContinueCommand_DoWork, () => true);

    }

    // Continue Command
    public void ContinueCommand_DoWork(object obj)
    {
        ObservableCollection<Room> RoomsSelected = new ObservableCollection<Room>();

        RoomsSelected = _getRoomsService.FilterSelectedRooms(RoomsList);

        //Publish event:
        _eventAggregator.GetEvent<RoomsSelectedEvent>().Publish(RoomsSelected);

        // Open new dialog
        _dialogServiceContactView.ShowDialog();
    }

}
```

**3: Inject IEventAggregator in subscriber viewModel (ContactViewModel)**

```
public class ContactViewModel : IViewContactViewModel, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //aggregator 
    protected readonly IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;

    //properties
    public ObservableCollection<Room> SelectedRooms { get; set; }

    public ContactViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        //Injection
        _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;

        //Subscripe to event
        _eventAggregator.GetEvent<RoomsSelectedEvent>()
        .Subscribe((data) => { SelectedRooms = data; });
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Room> Rooms
    {
        get { return SelectedRooms; }
        set { SelectedRooms = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

}
```

I have read it's maybe because of the IEventAggregator is not the same in both ViewModels. I'm using Unity to inject it like this code:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        //view & viewModels
        _container = new UnityContainer();
        _container.RegisterType<IViewMainWindowViewModel, MainWindow>();
        _container.RegisterType<IViewMainWindowViewModel, MenuViewModel>();
        _container.RegisterType<IViewBookingViewModel, BookingView>();
        _container.RegisterType<IViewBookingViewModel, BookingViewModel>();
        _container.RegisterType<IViewContactViewModel, ContactDetailsView>();
        _container.RegisterType<IViewContactViewModel, ContactViewModel>();
        _container.RegisterType<IGetRoomsService, GetRoomsService>();
        _container.RegisterType<IPostReservationService, PostReservationService>();
        _container.RegisterType<IGetReservationsListService, GetReservationsListService>();

        //types
         _container.RegisterType<IEventAggregator, EventAggregator>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
        _container.RegisterType(typeof(IDialogService<>), typeof(DialogService<>));

        _container.Resolve<MainWindow>().Show();
    }
```

Found that I need to add the ContainerControlledLifetimeManager, but it still wont work.

When I debug in the subscriber viewModel, I can see that there is an event inside the instance, like on the image:

[image: Debug of subscriber]

It wont catch it , thats the problem :(

Today I tried delete all packages I installed (prism 5.0) and go for the Prism.Core (6.1 version)

That resulted in the same, I can see when I debug that the event in published, but when I subscribe, it's still null.

Comment: `EventAggregator` is automatically registered by the `UnityBootstrapper` base class , you don't need to do that yourself. Also, both viewmodels have to be alive at the same time.

Comment: And looking at your code, you _really_ want to use the bootstrapper rather than implementing all the stuff yourself.