# How should communicate child ViewModel and main ViewModel according to MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have View with `TabControl` and `Button`. My `ViewModel` began to grow fast, so I decided to split it into a couple of ViewModels for each `TabItem`. I want my `Button` IsEnabled property depends on if any checkbox checked in first TabItem. 
So my question is how should child ViewModel communicate with main ViewModel.  Here is my code for View:

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem DataContext="{Binding TabItem1ViewModel}">
        <ListBox ItemSource="{Binding Items}>
            <ListBoxt.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                   <Checkbox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Text="{Binding Text}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                    <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding SelectionChangedCommand}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </ListBox>
    </TabItem>
    //...... Another TabItems
</TabControl>

<Button IsEnabled="{Binding IsAnythingChecked}" Content=""/>
```

for ViewModel:

```
MainViewModel:BaseViewModel
{
   public TabItem1ViewModel TabItem1ViewModel {get;set;}

   public bool IsAnythingChecked 
   {
      get
      {
          return TabItem1ViewModel.Items.Any(x=>x.IsChecked);
      }
   }
}

TabItem1ViewModel:BaseViewModel
{
   public TabItem1ViewModel()
   {
      SelectionChangedCommand = new RelayCommand(selectionChanged);
   }

   public Model Items {get;set;}

   public ICommand SelectionChangedCommand {get;set;}

   private void selectionChanged()
   {
       //...
       //Some logic here
       //...
       //And I want to update IsAnythingChecked property of MainViewModel what is the best way to do it?
   }
}
```

for Model:

```
class Model:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public bool IsChecked { get;set; }

   public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Also, is it a good practice to split ViewModel into smaller ones or fat ViewModel is also ok?

Comment: how to communicate between viewModels 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36649937/passing-data-from-one-vm-to-another-vm-when-using-unity-di-resolvet-showdia/36650342#36650342

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole point of view model is to separate concerns.

To answer your questions:

### 1. How should communicate child ViewModel and main ViewModel according to MVVM?

The most common approach that I use and feel at home is with a common message bus. Where you take an instance of e.g. `IMessenger` in the constructor and then can use it to push events that happen in your view model, and any other interested view model (in your case, your main view model) can subscribe to those events.

Depending what library you are using there probably already is a basic pub/sub messaging bus already implemented (e.g. PRISM or MVVMLight). I will post some links shortly.

### 2. Is it a good practice to split ViewModel into smaller ones or fat ViewModel is also ok

Definitely, go for smaller view models. If you are testing at all, it is much easier to test smaller view models, and easier for next person to come along and understand what a smaller view model is supposed to do, rather than a mother of all view models! Part of SOLID is Single Responsibility Principal, which really helps when it comes to maintenance and/or testing.